# Visual Basic date format validator not working?

Tags: vb.net, date, validation, format

I am trying to create a program which validates the format of an inputted date in the format DDMMYYYY. I have tried to use a collection of `while` loops to do this, however it doesn't seem to work, and I cannot figure out why!

Here is my code:

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter your date of birth (DDMMYYYY): ")
            Dim dob As String = Console.ReadLine
            While CInt(Mid(dob, 3, 2)) > 12 Or CInt(Mid(dob, 3, 2)) < 1
                Console.WriteLine("x-----x")
                Console.WriteLine("Format Incorrect!")
                Console.WriteLine("Enter your date of birth: ")
                dob = Console.ReadLine
            End While
            While CInt(Mid(dob, 3, 2)) = 4 Or 6 Or 9 Or 1 And CInt(Mid(dob, 1, 2)) > 30
                Console.WriteLine("x-----x")
                Console.WriteLine("Format Incorrect!")
                Console.WriteLine("Enter your date of birth: ")
                dob = Console.ReadLine
            End While
            While CInt(Mid(dob, 3, 2)) = 2 And CInt(Mid(dob, 1, 2)) > 29
                Console.WriteLine("x-----x")
                Console.WriteLine("Format Incorrect!")
                Console.WriteLine("Enter your date of birth: ")
                dob = Console.ReadLine
            End While
            While CInt(Mid(dob, 1, 2)) < 1
                Console.WriteLine("x-----x")
                Console.WriteLine("Format Incorrect!")
                Console.WriteLine("Enter your date of birth: ")
            End While
            Console.WriteLine("Thank You!")
```

I have researched other methods, but I haven't found any solutions which fit what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second while loop, you have written:

`CInt(Mid(dob, 3, 2)) = 4 Or 6 Or 9 Or 1`.

This syntax is incorrect, since there should be a statement that can evaluate to true or false between each boolean operator (Or/And etc) - not just a number. Try this:

```
Dim month As Integer = CInt(Mid(dob, 3, 2))
While (month = 4 Or month = 6 Or month = 9 Or month = 11) And CInt(Mid(dob, 1, 2)) > 30
```

Hopefully from that you can see what I mean. Notice that I have also put parentheses around all of the `Or` operators so that it will be interpreted as *(a or b or c or d) and e* instead of *(a or b or c) or (d and e)*.

Comment: @Mary You can use SubString, but I wanted to keep the answer concise and explain the actual problem, rather than give the perfect solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [DateTime.TryParseExact()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparseexact). An example:

```
Sub Main()
    Console.WriteLine("Enter your date of birth (DDMMYYYY): ")
    Dim d As Date
    Do
        Dim dob = Console.ReadLine
        If DateTime.TryParseExact(dob, "ddMMyyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, d) Then
            Exit Do
        End If
        Console.WriteLine("Please try again, pay particular attention to the format, no spaces or other characters.")
    Loop
    'you now have a real date called d
    Debug.Print(d.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"))
    Console.WriteLine("Thank You!")
    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
```